# Netstat continous mode on Android

Tags: android, netstat, lineageos

I tried to run netstat on Android (specifically LineageOS) and I saw that it has only these options:

- -r      Routing table
- -a      All sockets (not just connected)
- -l      Listening server sockets
- -t      TCP sockets
- -u      UDP sockets
- -w      Raw sockets
- -x      Unix sockets
- -e      Extended info
- -n      Don't resolve names
- -W      Wide display
- -p      Show PID/program name of sockets

On Ubuntu, there is also -c, for **continous mode**, which prints netstat every second. Is there a way to do the same on Android?
I tried

```
watch -n 1 "netstat -autpn"
```

But this will just run netstat every second, losing information that comes in between those seconds. Is there another version of netstat I can use, or maybe a way to build my own version of netstat?

Thank you!